# Remove contents of the end of a string where the contents appear in variable order without effecting the rest of the string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a list of over 6000 strings, these strings are company names.  Appended to the end of these strings are C,E,B,BE,C/CARD,CE/,BNOE.  These appended characters can be in any order (or not exist at all) and have any number of spaces between them seemingly dependent upon how many times the accounts department wanted to jump on the spacebar.  I need to remove these impurities from the string without effecting the company names (which obvious may include 'B', 'C', 'BE', etc... and may end in 'E', 'C', etc...)

The factor which can distinguish C,E,B,BE,C/CARD,CE/,BNOE existence is that they always have a space which precedes them.  As such, I thought that I could split the string by spaces, check each element for a match (of C,E,B,BE,C/CARD,CE/,BNOE) and remove accordingly.  But this seems very basic, is there a better way to do this?

Example of strings:

```
COMPANY NAME (26 spaces) C/CARD

COMPANY NAME (15 spaces) C/CARD E

COMPANY NAME (5 spaces) B E CE/ C/CARD
```

Comment: if `this seems very basic` why don't you at least post a attempted solution

Comment: Please show us what you've attempted and a demonstration you've actually tried.

Comment: I would appreciate if you'd remove these comments for obvious reasons.  Please consider constructive feedback in future replies.

Comment: I have asked a coding question, supplied a theoretical resolution, asked the Stack community for other methodical resolutions, and received code-based replies.  Please supply the grounds on which people feel this movement is off-topic.  I don't feel that the lack of a simple split and remove piece of code in the initial question is adequate to invalidate the whole discourse.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach it like this:

```
lst = s.split(' ') # split by spaces
while lst [-1] in ["", "B", "E", "C/CARD" ...]: # define items to remove
    lst  = lst[:-1] # remove last item
s = " ".join(lst) # put it back together
```

Note that this works for `"That E Company"` but would break down e.g. if the company name was `"Some Company E"`.

Comment: If I were to haphazard a guess I'd say it would be very difficult to correctly parse the data stream into something sensible seeing as the OP describes the data as basically garbage :/